All four children have England birth index page changes
I am researching fourth cousins following a DNA match, and for each of them that I find, I always record their birth index details.
These particular cousins that were born in Norfolk in England, between late 1960s and early 1970s, have the page numbers crossed out with new pages hand-written with an "/S" at the end.
I can accept that the odd record was transcribed wrong when the index was typed up, but all four of them must have some significance. Does it stand for "Sensitive" or "Special"??
Any ideas?

This is definitely a question for the local registration office. They would know their own shorthand.

Did you really mean 'fourth' cousins, or the more likely 'four'?

An amended page number would generally indicated a re-registration or correction, more often than not due to illegitimacy.
According to the FreeBMD FAQS:

Each quarter the Superintendent Registrar for a district sends copies of his/her register entries to the General Register Office who then apply a page number to the records for indexing purposes.
However, in some circumstances, e.g. when a birth is re-registered, a further supplementary copy is sent by the Registrar to the General Register Office which supersedes the original copy and in these cases the new entry is given a supplementary number.
This means an original page number in an entry such as 495 might be crossed out and replaced by a page number such as 1659/S or the supplementary number might just be added to the page number.
There are a number of reasons for re-registering a birth, such as:

If at the time of registration the mother was not married to the
baby's father, but they have since married, it is a legal duty to
re-register the birth, even when the father's details were entered
when the birth was originally registered.
If the natural father's details were not recorded at the initial registration but there is now a wish to add them.



A possible explanation, is if the children were illegitimate then they would often be registered under only the mother's name. If the parents later married, then the children would be legitimised and could be re-registered under the father’s name as well. You might need to order some of the certificates to explore that.
Or you could contact the local registration office in Norfolk where the events were registered and ask them if they can explain what had happened.

That advice from FreeBMD is incorrect, they are mixing corrections and re-registrations which are two completely different processes.
A correction is a change to the entry which results in an amended copy of the existing entry to be submitted to GRO. These appear in the newer on-line GRO index as "Occasional Copy A" or B/C if there was more than one change over time.
A re-registration creates a completely new register entry which may be cross-referenced to the original in the written indexes (not always). It can be months or years after the first registration.
It does not supercede the original ( in the sense of closing it) and certificates can be obtained from both.
Your "S" annotation probably indicates a supplementary submission, so would indicate a change/correction of some sort but there is no way of knowing what it was without getting a copy of the entry.

I agree the FreeBMD information is a bit unclear. I thought the "/S" likely indicated a correction rather than re-registration. However it's difficult to say for sure without seeing the actual entries, as the annotations in the old GRO indexes don't always seem to be consistent.
